# Why this function couldn't return right result?

Tags: python, function, numpy, random

## Result is not same actual values.For example, in this case from my output only first observation is same as actual.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

def emil(values):
    output = np.empty(len(values))
        for i in range(len(values)):
            output[i] = 1.0 / values[i]
            print(len(values))
        return output

values = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=6)
print(emil(values))

   
Out[1]: array([ 0.16666667, 1. , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.125 ])
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you are looking for. What is your expected output?

Comment: Could you only explain how to work this code piece

Comment: What result do you want to get? It works as expected. It takes an array of integers and returns their inverses.

Comment: what are the expected results ?

Comment: Could you show us the content of `values`? As it is randomly generated we cannot tell if something is wrong. My guess is `[6, 1, 4, 4, 8]`? If that is the case then nothing is wrong your code.

Comment: @Silveris Actually I believe it's always the same because he sets a constant seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes from the [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) of your random generator
A seed is helpful to retrieve a deterministic serie of randoms.
As your seed is set to 0 :

```py
np.random.seed(0)
```

Every random generation will still be the same (because the same seed is used)
If you remove this line, the code will generate unseeded random numbers and will have a random behavior (which is what you were expecting)